# node.js проблемы с работоспособностью

Tags: node.js

Была стандартная сборка Node.js(6.9.5) express, socket.io mysql, всё работало , сокеты отправлялись всё срабатывало как надо, до установил пакеты Brain, Redis, promise-mysql начились неизвестные неполадки, при работе сокетов выявилась проблема с задержкой выполнения действия в 1 шаг. 
Пример 
На клиенте тыкаем Button  
на сервере

```
 socket.on('Card stol', function (data) {
 console.log(arr); // -> пустой
 arr.push (data);
 console.log(arr); //-> пусткой 
 });
```

На клиенте тыкаем Button 2 раз

```
socket.on('Card stol', function (data) {
console.log(arr); // -> пустой
arr.push (data);
console.log(arr); //-> 1
});
```

Может кто сталкивался, пытался использовать promisse, callback и т.д. ничего не решает проблему, пока сборку не пересобирал.

```
socket.on('Card stol', function (data) {
connectionMy.query('SELECT * FROM batle_brain ').then(function(row){
return row;
}).then(function(row){
if(row[0] !== 'undefined'){
for(var i = 0 ;  i < row.length; i++){
console.log(row[i].h1); // выводит, запрос есть данные есть
persipton.push({
input: [row[i].h1, row[i].d1, row[i].b1, row[i].s1,row[i].h2, row[i].d2,      row[i].b2, row[i].s2 ],
output: [row[i].r]
}); 
console.log(persipton); // пустой на выходе
} 
} 
console.log(persipton);
if(persipton === []  ||  persipton === 'undefined' ||   persipton.length  === 0 ) { }else {
net.train(persipton);
var output = net.run([0.003,0.02,0.2,0.1,1,0,0,0]); 
console.log(output); 
}
});

});
```

Comment: Честно говоря, в такое поведение верится с трудом. `arr` - обычный нативный массив?

Comment: нет , сложный массивный объект

Comment: Значит, нужна его реализация. Конкретно интересует метод `push`

Comment: Добавил, код можете посмотреть